# Linear nonhomogenous relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics

In the book `Discrete mathematics and its applications` (Kenneth H. Rosen) in the page  472 has given us this example: What is the general solution of the linear nonhomogeneous relation $a_n=8a_{n-1}-16a_{n-2}+ F(n)$, where

$a)$ $F(n)=n^2(-2)^n$

$b)$ $F(n)=n2^n$

$c)$ $F(n)=n^24^n$

$d)$ $F(n)=(n^2-2)(-2)^n$

$e)$ $F(n)=n^42^n$

I know that, to find out the general solution must be assigned sum of the homogeneous solution and the particular solution of the linear nonhomogeneous relation $a_n=8a_{n-1}-16a_{n-2}$.
My attempt is:
Associated homogeneous recurrence relation is: $a_n=8a_{n-1}-16a_{n-2}.$
Characteristic equation: $r^2-8r+16=0$. Characteristic root is $r_0=4.$ So $a_n^{(h)}=\alpha4^n+\beta n4^n.$

But i didnt know how to find the particular solution. Help me to find the particular solution $a_n^{(p)}.$ I think so

$a)$  $a_n^{(p)}=(p_1n^2+p_2n+p_3)(-2)^n$

$b)$  $a_n^{(p)}=(p_1n+p_2)2^n$

$c)$  $a_n^{(p)}=(p_1n^2+p_2n+p_3)4^n$

$d)$  $a_n^{(p)}=(p_1n^2+p_2n+p_3)(-2)^n$

$e)$  $a_n^{(p)}=(p_1n^4+p_2n^3+p_3n^2+p_4n+p_5)2^n$

but I don't know if it's good. HELP me please.

Comment: Are they okay??

Comment: Patience, betmen, patience.

Comment: c) won't work, since $(p_2n+p_3)4^n$ is already a solution to the homogeneous equation.

Comment: Do you understand my comment about c), betmen?

Answer (score 1):

Let us focus the first option as $F(n) = n^2(-2)^n$

The homogeneous as you found is

$$
a_n^h = (\alpha + n\beta)(-2)^{2n}
$$

proposing a particular with the structure

$$
a_n^p = (\alpha_n + n\beta_n)(-2)^{2n}
$$

substituting into the particular we have

$$
(\alpha_n + n\beta_n)(-2)^{2n} = 2(\alpha_{n-1}+(n-1)\beta_{n-1})(-2)^{2n}-(\alpha_{n-2}+(n-2)\beta_{n-2})(-2)^{2n}+n^2(-2)^n
$$

or

$$
(\alpha_n + n\beta_n)= 2(\alpha_{n-1}+(n-1)\beta_{n-1})-(\alpha_{n-2}+(n-2)\beta_{n-2})+n^2(-2)^{-n}
$$

now, as $\alpha_n,\beta_n$ are independent we can choose them such that

$$
\cases{
\alpha_n-2\alpha_{n-1}+\alpha_{n-2} = n^2(-2)^{-n}\\
n\beta_n-2(n-1)\beta_{n-1}+(n-2)\beta_{n-2}=0
}
$$

or calling $\gamma_n = n\beta_n$

$$
\cases{
\alpha_n-2\alpha_{n-1}+\alpha_{n-2} = n^2(-2)^{-n}\\
\gamma_n-2\gamma_{n-1}+\gamma_{n-2}=0
}
$$

and now with $u_n = \alpha_n-\alpha_{n-1}$ and $v_n = \gamma_n-\gamma_{n-1}$ we obtain

$$
\cases{
u_n-u_{n-1} = n^2(-2)^{-n}\\
v_n-v_{n-1} = 0
}
$$

Those recurrences can be  easily solved, giving also easy recurrences for $\alpha_n,\beta_n$ so we can obtain this way, a particular solution.

NOTE

When calculating particular solutions we can choose the constants at our convenience.